# Checking a CSV file for multiple strings

Tags: python, csv

This seems like an easy problem but I can't figure it out right now. I have the following CSV file:

```
Version,4
Name,Jon
Address,Somewhere
Date,09-16-2016
Worked,Yes
Done,No
Description,Something
```

I want to check if this CSV contains several of the fields in column A and contains the related values in column B.

My code looks something like this:

```
import csv
f = csv.reader(open(file.csv))
fields = ['Name','Address','Date']
```

Now I want to do some specific logic if I find a field and/or the related value, for example:

```
for r in f:
    if r[0] in fields:
        print(r[0]+" is present in the file.csv file")
        if r[1]:
            print("Value related to "+r[0]+" is in the file.csv file")
            if r[0] == 'Date': 
                if type(datetime.datetime.strptime(r[1], '%m-%d-%Y')) == datetime.datetime:
                    print(r[0]+" value is correctly formatted")
                else:
                    print(r[0]+" value is not correctly formatted (MM-DD-YYYY)")
                    break
        else:
            print("Value related to "+r[0]+" is not filled in, in the file.csv file")
            break
```

This works but how would I now check if any of the strings in the `fields` list are not in the CSV in this loop? Any other remarks are welcome too.

Comment: if you add else part for `if r[0] in fields:` statement and handle it, then what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @paul_dg is ``pandas`` an option?

Comment: @Haranadh That would return all values in r[0] that are not in fields. I want to retrieve which of values in fields that ar not in the CSV.

Comment: @Meitham a solution using standard libraries would be more appropriate for my case at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be simple if you're willing to give `pandas` a go::

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, names=['A', 'B'])
>>> df
             A           B
0      Version           4
1         Name         Jon
2      Address   Somewhere
3         Date  09-16-2016
4       Worked         Yes
5         Done          No
6  Description   Something

>>> fields = ['Name','Address','Date']
>>> df.ix[:, 'C'] = df['A'].isin(fields)
>>> df
             A           B      C
0      Version           4  False
1         Name         Jon   True
2      Address   Somewhere   True
3         Date  09-16-2016   True
4       Worked         Yes  False
5         Done          No  False
6  Description   Something  False
```

Alternatively, you could try ::

```
>>> import csv
... f = csv.reader(open('file.csv'))
... fields = ['Name','Address','Date']
... 
... 
>>> items = dict(f)
>>> items
{'Name': 'Jon', 'Version': '4', 'Done': 'No', 'Address': 'Somewhere', 'Date': '09-16-2016', 'Worked': 'Yes', 'Description': 'Something'}
>>> defined_keys = {k: v for k, v in items.items() if k in fields}
>>> defined_keys
{'Date': '09-16-2016', 'Name': 'Jon', 'Address': 'Somewhere'}
>>> undefined_keys = {k: v for k, v in items.items() if k not in fields}
>>> undefined_keys
{'Worked': 'Yes', 'Version': '4', 'Done': 'No', 'Description': 'Something'}
>>>
```

The right data structure here depends on what are all the processes/operations you intend to do with the data. A `DataFrame` is very flexible in that aspect, but if you prefer to roll your own, then the `dict` here might do.

Answer (score 1):

For a standard library approach, perhaps something like:

```
import csv
import datetime

reader = csv.reader(open('file.csv'))
file_contents = {}
for line in reader:
    file_contents[line[0]] = line[1]

def is_date(s):
    return isinstance(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%m-%d-%Y'), datetime.datetime)

fields = [('Name',lambda s: isinstance(s,str)),
          ('Address',lambda s: isinstance(s,str)),
          ('Date',is_date)]
for field,arg_check in fields:
    if field not in file_contents:
        print('Missing field {}'.format(field))
        break
    val = file_contents[field]
    if not arg_check(val):
        print('field {} with value {} failed arg check'.format(field,val))
        break
```

Here I blindly read all the csv values into a dictionary, then have a list of tuples that specifies what's expected. `fields` specifies the field name followed by a function that returns True or False when called with the value of that field as its argument.